# How Do I Move Remote Desktop User Profiles To Another Volume?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote, users, desktop, user-profile

I am new to Windows Server 2008 and Remote Desktops, and have a handful of users (5) accessing a suite of applications by way of Remote Desktop sessions. The server is set up with a RAID 5 drive that is split into two partitions; 80GB on the C: boot drive and about 850GB on the D: data drive. When a domain user first opens an RD session the system creates a new user profile in C:\Users, and I'd like to have them stored in D:\Users instead.

So far the closest I've come to achieving this is by using Junctions to direct the system to save the user data on the other volume; ran into a major snag when we found one of the applications would refuse to launch when in RD on the second volume.

I'm continuing to investigate this, but would appreciate any help in getting this accomplished with little hassle. I'm betting there is some obscure setting that can be modified to put them elsewhere, but I have yet to find it. And if there are better ways of accomplishing this, please share; I'm all ears!

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to configure RDS roaming profiles for the users.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/06/02/user-profiles-on-windows-server-2008-r2-remote-desktop-services.aspx

http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/08/best-practice-roaming-profiles-and-folder-redirection-a-k-a-user-virtualization

Comment: The important part of Roaming profiles is to use Folder redirection on almost everything, otherwise your profiles will get very large and logins will take a long time.

Comment: Right. Roaming profiles and Folder Redirection should go hand in hand.